# How Display notification on mobile and desktop when your qt quick application is not running?

Tags: qt, push-notification, asp.net-web-api2, qt-quick

I have a qt quick application that will run on desktop(windows) and mobile(android) platforms .Now I need to check my asp.net web api for how many message this user have and then if needed ,display a notification to user,when my application is not running and in the background?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your web api you used. For example, if you use Firebase (google), it's possible to use C++ Api to manage notifications on iOS and android platforms. There are many tutorials on the web and a good documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/

You need to create tokens and to connect your device to the API and after, from Firebase you will be able to send notifications to all devices connected to the service.